# rostest not finding the actual test

Tags: rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am trying to create a functional test. My node is a C++ ROS node for face detection which works independently. My test file (functional_tests.py) follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
PKG='ros_nodes'

import sys
import unittest
import rospy
from rapp_platform_ros_communications.srv import *

class FaceDetFunc(unittest.TestCase):

    def faceDetectionFunctionalTest(self):
        rospy.wait_for_service('ric/face_detection_service')
        fd_service = rospy.ServiceProxy('ric/face_detection_service', FaceDetectionRosSrv)
        req = FaceDetectionRosSrv.Request
        req.imageFilename = "/home/etsardou/rapp_platform_catkin_ws/src/rapp-platform/ric/test_auxiliary_files/Lenna.png"
        response = fd_service(req)
        faces_num = len(response.faces_up_left)
        self.assertEqual( faces_num, 1, "Face detection ok")
       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import rosunit
    rosunit.unitrun(PKG, 'FaceDetFunc', FaceDetFunc)
```

My launch file for the functional test is:

```
<launch> 
   <node type="face_detection_ros_node" pkg="ros_nodes" name="ros_nodes"/> 
   <test time-limit="10" test-name="face_detection_functional" pkg="ros_nodes" type="functional_tests.py" /> 
</launch>
```

The CMake:

```
if (CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
  add_rostest(test/face_detection/functional_tests.launch)
endif()
```

The output I get is:

```
$ catkin_make run_tests_ros_nodes_rostest_test_face_detection_functional_tests.launch 
Base path: /home/etsardou/rapp_platform_catkin_ws
Source space: /home/etsardou/rapp_platform_catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/etsardou/rapp_platform_catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/etsardou/rapp_platform_catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/etsardou/rapp_platform_catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/etsardou/rapp_platform_catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make run_tests_ros_nodes_rostest_test_face_detection_functional_tests.launch -j2 -l2" in "/home/etsardou/rapp_platform_catkin_ws/build"
####
Scanning dependencies of target run_tests_ros_nodes_rostest_test_face_detection_functional_tests.launch
-- run_tests.py: execute commands
  /home/etsardou/rosjava/src/ros_comm/tools/rostest/scripts/rostest --pkgdir=/home/etsardou/rapp_platform_catkin_ws/src/rapp-platform/ric/ros_nodes --package=ros_nodes --results-filename test_face_detection_functional_tests.xml /home/etsardou/rapp_platform_catkin_ws/src/rapp-platform/ric/ros_nodes/test/face_detection/functional_tests.launch 
... logging to /home/etsardou/.ros/log/rostest-iason-24881.log
[ROSUNIT] Outputting test results to /home/etsardou/rapp_platform_catkin_ws/build/test_results/ros_nodes/rostest-test_face_detection_functional_tests.xml
libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
testface_detection_functional ... ok

[ROSTEST]-----------------------------------------------------------------------


SUMMARY
 * RESULT: SUCCESS
 * TESTS: 0
 * ERRORS: 0
 * FAILURES: 0

rostest log file is in /home/etsardou/.ros/log/rostest-iason-24881.log
-- run_tests.py: verify result "/home/etsardou/rapp_platform_catkin_ws/build/test_results/ros_nodes/rostest-test_face_detection_functional_tests.xml"
Built target run_tests_ros_nodes_rostest_test_face_detection_functional_tests.launch
```

Thus, my test is not found. Btw I am running another test from the same ws and it runs correctly (the files are almost the same).

Edit: A part of the log file that does not have an error or something..:

```
[rostest][INFO] 2014-11-14 09:30:03,872: process[face_detection_functional-3]: started with pid [9818]
[roslaunch][INFO] 2014-11-14 09:30:03,874: ... successfully launched [face_detection_functional-3]
[rostest][INFO] 2014-11-14 09:30:04,403: [face_detection_functional-3] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/etsardou/.ros/log/0c6ea6a8-6bd0-11e4-8c35-9a10b4a777d2/face_detection_functional-3*.log
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2014-11-14 09:30:04,403: ProcessMonitor.unregister[face_detection_functional-3] starting
[roslaunch.pmon][INFO] 2014-11-14 09:30:04,404: ProcessMonitor.unregister[face_detection_functional-3] complete
[rostest][INFO] 2014-11-14 09:30:04,477: test [face_detection_functional] finished
[rostest][INFO] 2014-11-14 09:30:04,477: test [face_detection_functional] results are in [/home/etsardou/rapp_platform_catkin_ws/build/test_results/ros_nodes/rosunit-face_detection_functional.xml]
[rostest][INFO] 2014-11-14 09:30:04,480: test [face_detection_functional] results summary: 0 errors, 0 failures, 0 tests
[rostest][INFO] 2014-11-14 09:30:04,481: [ROSTEST] test [face_detection_functional] done
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197377/rostest-not-finding-the-actual-test/) by [etsardou](https://answers.ros.org/users/10001/etsardou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-11-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-11-13**:
Did you look in the rostest log file? Also the error `libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394` might be related?

**Comment by [etsardou](https://answers.ros.org/users/10001/etsardou/) on 2014-11-14**:
The log file did not have any errors.. (I edited the initial message by adding a small portion of the log file).

Also the libdc1394 has to do with OpenCV and not with ROS [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689304/ctypes-error-libdc1394-error-failed-to-initialize-libdc1394).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rename the test suite method into: `test_faceDetectionFunctional`. Unittest needs the test suites to be named like `test_something`.

If this doesn't suffice, switch to rostest instead of rosunit.
http://wiki.ros.org/rostest

then your main should look like:
`rostest.rosrun(PKG, NAME, FaceDecFunc, sys.argv)`

with
`PKG = 'ros_nodes'` and `NAME` whatever this test is named.

---

Originally posted by [Tsirif](https://answers.ros.org/users/4683/tsirif/) with karma: 106 on 2014-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [etsardou](https://answers.ros.org/users/10001/etsardou/) on 2014-11-15**:
The rename has hone it! Thnx ;)